# python merging unsorted lists - algorithm analysis

Tags: python, algorithm, list, sorting, big-o

Given two arrays with the following structure:

```
array = [(index_1, item_1), (index_2, item_2), ..., (index_n, item_n)]
```

Inside the array the items can be un-orderd, for example two Python lists:

```
arr1 = [(1,'A'), (2, 'B'), (3,'C')]
arr2 = [(3,'c'), (2, 'b'), (1,'a')]
```

I would like analyze the merge of those arrays. There are two ways I could think of doing a merge. The first one would be the naive iteration over both
arrays:

```
merged = []
for item in arr:
    for item2 in arr2:
        if item[0] == item2[0]:
            merged.append((item[0], item[1], item2[1]))

# merged
# [(1, 'A', 'a'), (2, 'B', 'b'), (3, 'C', 'c')]
```

This naive approach be in big-o O(n**2),

A slightly better(?) approach would be to sort the arrays first (with Python sort being O(n log n)):

```
arr.sort(key=lambda t: t[0])
arr2.sort(key=lambda t: t[0])

for idx, item in enumerate(arrs):
    merged_s.append(tuple(list(item)+[arr2s[idx][1]]))
```

So this approach would be O(n log n) in total, is this analysis correct?
What about the case where the lists have unequal lengths `m` and `n`?
Is there a more efficient way then sorting both first?

Comment: What should be the output if the items are missing?

Comment: Are you saying that the length of two arrays will always be the same?

Comment: `tuple(list(item)+[arr2s[idx][1]])` could be `item+arr2s[idx][1:]`. As the slice of a tuple is a tuple and `+` concatenates tuples just like lists.

Comment: @thefourtheye, If an element index is missing in one array, it should be skipped. I guess this answered my question about different lengths m and n.

Comment: @Shrey, see my comment to thefourtheye

Comment: Is the first element (the key) always a number?  Do you need the final list to be sorted by the first element?  And finally, how sparse are the keys?  e.g. is the number of elements proportional to the maximum key value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of your analysis, you're correct on both counts.

Assuming n > m: your first example runs at O(n*m), your second O(nlogn) as the larger sort dominates the smaller sort.  (**NB:** Assuming it runs!  the second method has a good chance of causing bugs when n!=m - either raising an index error if `len(arr1) > len(arr2)`, or it will miss items at the end of `arr2`)

We can probably do better.
Given that your first sample doesn't ensure ordered output, I'm assuming that's not a requirement.  If so, the below will a) run in O(n+m) and b) skip items where the key was not found in both lists.

```
import itertools
arr1 = [(1,'A'), (2, 'B'), (3,'C'), (4, 'D')]
arr2 = [(3,'c'), (2, 'b'), (1,'a'), (5, 'E')]

output_dict = {}
for key, value in itertools.chain(arr1, arr2): # I like itertools
    output_dict.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
output = [(key,)+tuple(values) for key, values in output_dict.items() if len(values)==2]
```

The output will be:

```
[(1, 'A', 'a'), (2, 'B', 'b'), (3, 'C', 'c')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr1 = [(1,'A'), (2, 'B'), (3,'C')]
arr2 = [(3,'c'), (2, 'b'), (1,'a')]
key2value = dict()
for item in arr1:
    key2value[item[0]] = [item[1]]
for item in arr2:
    try:
        value = key2value[item[0]]
        value.append(item[1])
    except:
        key2value[item[0]] = [item[1]]

result = [tuple([key] + value) for key, value in key2value.iteritems()]
```

The time complexity is O(m+n), where m = len(arr1) and n = len(arr2), but this method cost more memory space

Answer (score 0):

`O(N Log(N))` complexity must be preferred over `O(N²)`. Compare `1000.Log2(1000) ~ 9966` to `1000² = 1000000`.

Anyway, all analyses on this page are wrong, as they assume that the operations on Python structures such as append or dictionary insertion take constant time, which is false.

Comment: What makes you say that? Python wiki says otherways https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: Because they do not account for the overhead of dynamic memory allocation/deallocation.

Comment: What would be that complexity? Does this change my analysis?

Comment: The time complexity of dynamic memory allocation is OS dependent, non-deterministic and undocumented. Of course it influences the running time of your code, in a unknown way.

Comment: So this means my analysis is also wrong? If this is undocumented, how can even use the big-o notation?

Comment: You can't, that's my point. Algorithm analysis requires that you model the complete process, which practically rules out dynamic allocation.